# Shift blank line after this line to before this line in Vim

Tags: regex, vim, substitution

I have following text:

```
A simple line
TITLE1:

Another usual line
TITLE2:

More usual lines here
TITLE3:

Last line of this sample text.
```

I want to convert above to:

```
A simple line

TITLE1:
Another usual line

TITLE2:
More usual lines here

TITLE3:
Last line of this sample text.
```

Hence, I want to remove the blank line that comes after the TITLE lines and instead add a blank line before the title lines. The TITLE lines are all identfied by ***ending with ':'***.

I tried following code

```
:%s/(.+):\r/\n\1:/g
```

but it does not work.

Comment: [`^(.+)$[\r\n]{2}` replace with `\n$1\n`](https://regex101.com/r/Bg2RoW/1/)

Comment: @ctwheels can you provide full answer based on this- proper command line and brief explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your requirement right, I would go with `:g//{cmd}` instead of `:s/../../` :

```
g/:$/norm JO
```

If you don't want to have the space after the `:`, add a `g` before `J`

### explanation:

```
:g/pat/norm JO
```

- for all lines matching `pat`, do normal mode command `J` and `O`.
- `J` does join, which means "removed" the next line break
- `O` adds an empty line before the current line.

You can move your cursor on the `TITLE` line press `JO` see what happens.

If you need further explanation/details, pls read:

```
:h :g
:h :norm
:h J  (or :h gJ)
:h O
```

Comment: Yes, it works very well. A brief explanation about how it works will be helpful to all.

Comment: @rnso as you wished. added in answer.

Comment: Excellent answer! Especially go with `:g//{cmd}` rather than substitution. Makes things so much simpler.

Comment: A bit shorter using `:move`. e.g. `:g/:/+m-`

Answer (score 1):

```
:g/TITLE/ m+1
```

How does it work?

```
: ............... command
g ............... global
/TITLE/ ......... all lines with TITLE
m+1 ............. move to the next line
```